# Instance method not printing anything

Tags: python

I found this code in a course I am following online:

```
#in this program we can make a car 
class car: 
    def __init__(self, brand, model, color):
        self.brand = brand 
        self.model = model 
        self.color = color 
        self.fuel_level = 20 
    def show(): 
        print(f"this is a {self.brand} {self.model} color {self.color}")
 print(f"the fuel level is {fuel_level} percent") mycar = car("peugeot", "2008", "blue")
mycar.show
```

I think it is because it uses classes and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: It does "do stuff". It created an instance... It's not meant to print anything, though. Did you miscopy `mycar.show()`?

Comment: `mycar.show` doesn't do anything. Call a function like `mycar.show()`

Comment: Please note that since indent matters in python, you need to make sure the code in your question is indented the way you meant for it to be indented. See [formatting help](/help/formatting) for help on how to format your questions for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called the method `show`, you have simply evaluated it.

The correct spelling of that last line is `mycar.show()`.